# Need a link in <f:selectItem> in JSF2.0

Tags: jsf-2

```
<h:selectOneRadio id="rating" layout="pageDirection">
     <f:selectItem id="one" itemLabel="Step 1 - "> 
          <h:outputLink>Click here</h:outputLink>
     </f:selectItem>
</h:selectOneRadio>
```

I need to have a link after every option within `f:selectItem`. How do I achieve this?

---

I get a JavaScript error event target value is null or not an object JavaScript error.
Anyways, this is what I am looking for.

```
<f:selectItem id="one" itemLabel="Step One" ><h:link>Click Here</h:link></f:selectItem>
```

It puts the Click Here NOT next to Step One but above it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `onclick` event of the `h:selectOneRadio` to change the location of the web app to the link given in the value of the `f:selectItem`

Here is how:

```
<h:form>
    <h:selectOneRadio id="rating" layout="pageDirection" onclick="var target = event.target || event.srcElement; window.location.href = target.value">
         <f:selectItem id="one" itemLabel="CNN" itemValue="http://www.cnn.com"/>
         <f:selectItem id="two" itemLabel="NBC" itemValue="http://www.nbc.com"/>
    </h:selectOneRadio>
</h:form>
```

Comment: Its 100% working , I tested it on my side... check your browser console for errors....

Comment: This approach fails in inferior browsers (read: IE<=8). You need `onclick="var target = event.target || event.srcElement; window.location.href = target.value"` instead.

Comment: Can I use h:link within f:selectItem

Comment: @user1842840 , I don't think that you can nest anything inside `f:selectItem` at least not `h:outputLink ` or `h:link`